# How to automatically login a user after registration in django

Tags: django

This is what I am currently using for registration:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Thanks for registering. Please login to continue.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response("accounts/register.html", {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Is it possible not to require the user to login manually after creating an account, but rather simply to log them in automatically? Thanks.

edit: I had tried the login() function without success. I believe the problem is that AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS was not set.

Comment: I think you can use this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Using the [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) and [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) functions:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Thanks for registering. You are now logged in.")
            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                    )
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this without success, but now I realize the problem was that I had not specified the backend. The lines:

    new_user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' 
    login(request, new_user)

do the trick. (Or should the backend be specified elsewhere rather than every time there is a registration?)

Comment: Set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` in `settings.py`. For further info, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends.

Comment: Even with that set, I get the error "'User' object has no attribute 'backend'"

Comment: Ah, you have to call `authenticate()` first otherwise there is no `backend` set. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I think setting 'new_user = ' twice is (part of) what tripped me up.

Comment: Another thing that tripped me up here was that you have to use raw strings when `authenticate`ing. I was trying to be clever and sneak it off the original `new_user` object, but I imagine that carried with it some of the references from the fields. That is, don't do: `new_user = authenticate(username = new_user.username, password = new_user.password)` rather get them from `POST` as the snippet describes or from the `form`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. It's probably better to use the validated form's fields as opposed to the POST data directly, incase they're modified for some reason during the validation. `new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])`

Comment: I've updated the answer as suggested by @Patrick. If you are using Django's `UserCreationForm`, note that the field name is `password1`, not `password`.

Comment: you can also use the decorator `from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods`  ... `@require_http_methods(["POST"])` instead of the first if check

Answer (score 12):

for class based views here was the code that worked for me (originally Django 1.7, updated for 2.1)

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import FormView

class SignUp(FormView):
    template_name = 'signup.html'
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url='/account'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #save the new user first
        form.save()
        #get the username and password
        username = self.request.POST['username']
        password = self.request.POST['password1']
        #authenticate user then login
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(self.request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url)
```

Comment: Why `authenticate(username=username, password=password)` is needed? why not just pass the user object?

Comment: @avi When you’re manually logging a user in, you must successfully authenticate the user with authenticate() before you call login(). authenticate() sets an attribute on the User noting which authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the backends documentation for details), and this information is needed later during the login process. An error will be raised if you try to login a user object retrieved from the database directly. Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: this didn't work out of the box in Django 2.1.4, I had to use a different return using `redirect`, see my separate [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179736/django-automatic-login-after-user-registration-2-1-4)

Comment: @sc28 I've updated the answer to work with later versions of Django.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work with Django 4.0 (for me, at least), or alternatively it doesn't work with custom user models that have custom user managers.

This is how I solved the issue (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31491942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68515276):

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from your.custom.user.models import User

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = ["username", "email", "password"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("success_url_name") # change this with your own URL

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # create the user object
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        # set password manually
        # as otherwise the User will be saved with unhashed password
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
        # save your User object to the database
        user.save()
        # get email and password
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        # authenticate your user with unhashed password, because `authenticate` hashes it again
        authenticated_user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        # log in
        login(self.request, authenticated_user)
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

You need to manually set the password, so that the database contains the **hashed** password. Without that, your unhashed password will be saved to the database, which will prevent you from logging in afterwards, as authentication involves hashing the password and checking that against the database.

Answer (score 2):

using only "login()" in django-4.0.3

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def registration(request):
if request.POST:
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')
        
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: I just tested with 4.0.3 on Python 3.10 and can confirm. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass Django's UserCreationForm and override it's save method to log them in when commit=True.

## forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A ModelForm for creating a User and logging 
    them in after commiting a save of the form.
    """

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        pass

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=commit)
        if commit:
            auth_user = authenticate(
                username=self.cleaned_data['username'], 
                password=self.cleaned_data['password1']
            )
            login(self.request, auth_user)

        return user
```

You just need to make sure you pass in a request object when you instantiate the form. You can do that by overriding the view's get_form_kwargs method.

## views.py

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return form_kwargs
```

Or, make sure when you instantiate a form_class you do `CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST, request=self.request)`.

Answer (score 1):

The Django [auth.login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) function makes it easy to log in a user, given a `request` and `User` instance.

Note: remember to add the necessary imports for the following examples.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
```

In a **function-based view**, the following should work.

```py
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()

    login(request, user)

    return redirect("desired-url")
```

For a **class-based view** (such as `CreateView` or `FormView`), you can override the `form_valid` method:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model and log the user in."""
    user = form.save()
    login(self.request, user)

    return redirect(self.success_url)
```