# Django automatic login after user registration (1.4)

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-authentication

I have an issue where I am successfully registering users - however, I want users to be logged in on registration. Here is the code that represents my registration view. Any thoughts on why the user is not auto-logged in?

Notes:

- The user is being registered correctly, they can log in after this
- authenticate(**kwargs) is returning the correct user
- In settings.py I have:

  ```
  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
  ```

Thanks!

```
def register(request):
    user_creation_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and user_creation_form.is_valid():
        u_name = user_creation_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        u_pass = user_creation_form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        user_creation_form.save()
        print u_name # Prints correct username
        print u_pass # Prints correct password
        user = authenticate(username=u_name,
                            password=u_pass)
        print 'User: ', user # Prints correct user
        login(request, user) # Seems to do nothing
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/book/') # User is not logged in on this page
    c = RequestContext(request, {'form': user_creation_form})
    return render_to_response('register.html', c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! I figured it out. In case anyone has this issue, import login from django.contrib.auth if you are calling it manually - I was importing the view. Commented out code represents the bad import for my situation.

```
# from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login
```

Answer (score 3):

I do it this way:

```
u.backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
login(request, u)
```

Answer (score 1):

for class based views here was the code that worked for me (django 1.7)

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views.generic import FormView

class SignUp(FormView):
   template_name = 'signup.html'
   form_class = UserCreationForm
   success_url='/account'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      #save the new user first
      form.save()
      #get the username and password
      username = self.request.POST['username']
      password = self.request.POST['password1']
      #authenticate user then login
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      login(self.request, user)
      return super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: your `form_class` should be `UserCreationForm` not `UserCreateForm` I think.

Comment: As I needed a solution for this, as @Patrick points out in the comment in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222549/how-to-automatically-login-a-user-after-registration-in-django, it is even better to authenticate with `authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])` in case something gets modified for some reason during the validation.

Comment: surely by using `django.views.generic.CreateView` instead of `django.views.generic.FormView` you could save yourself calling save, and use that at the top?

Comment: this didn't work out of the box in Django 2.1.4, I had to use a different return using `redirect`, see my separate [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179736/django-automatic-login-after-user-registration-2-1-4)