# Django user login after creation isn't working

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using django auth framework to do user registration, and then log the user in right away. Here's my code:

```
class SignUpView(FormMixin, ProcessFormView):
    http_method_names = ['post']

    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('default_page')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.cleaned_data['is_usertype_1']:
            self.success_url = reverse_lazy('some_page')

        form.save()

        user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if user is None:
            raise Exception("Could not authenticate the new user")

        login(self.request, user)

        return super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        pass
```

Basically, I have extended `UserCreationForm` to add `is_usertype_1` field, and displaying it as `BooleanField`. And using that data, I am determining where the user gets redirected to after the signup.

But the problem arises when I try to log the created user in. No Exception gets raised, but for some reason, subsequent redirects still holds `AnonymousUser` in request.user. But when I log in with the created user manually, login works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your form is valid?

Comment: Yes, the new user object do get saved in the DB (I'm calling form.save no where else). Also, just changed the form_invalid to raise exception, but nothing gets raised.

Comment: After `login(self.request, user)` try to check it: 

    `if user.is_authenticated():
        print(1)`

Comment: I added `if not user.is_authenticated(): raise Exception("user wasn't authenticated")` but no exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's the same issue as [Django automatic login after user registration (1.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192808/django-automatic-login-after-user-registration-1-4)

Following was my import statement:

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms as auth_forms, views as auth_views, login, authenticate
```

Changed it to

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms as auth_forms, views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login, authenticate as auth_authenticate
```

and updated all the `login` and `authenticate` call to `auth_login` and `auth_authenticate` and seems to work now.

Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but maybe super().form_valid() is saving the UserCreationForm a second time, which will call set_password() again, therefore setting a new salted password, invalidating your first login :)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/#UserCreationForm

Comment: `FormMixin` and `ProcessFormView` doesn't seem to have any `form.save()` call. Also, I tried overwriting `save` method to log whenever it gets called, and it seems that it only gets called once