# Django automatic login after user registration (2.1.4)

Tags: django

The automatic login of newly registered users is not working in the case of a "class-based" registration view.

I followed the example from [this tutorial](https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-signup/), which proposes the following registration view:

```
# myapp/views.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

I tried including the class-based solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28974691/3976696), but after successfully registering a new user, the login doesn't happen as expected. Are there changes in Django 2.1.4 which might cause this to malfunction?

`myapp.users.views`:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = '/index'
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    #auto login after register: 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        #save the new user first
        form.save()
        #get the username and password
        username = self.request.POST['username']
        password = self.request.POST['password1']
        #authenticate user then login
        user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
        login(self.request, user)
        return super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Django [invalidates sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change) after a password change. It might be that calling `super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)` after `login()` is triggering this. You can avoid this by calling `super()` earlier (as in the answer @ShafikurRahman linked to), or by doing `return redirect(self.success_url)` instead instead of calling `super()`.

Comment: Note that `super().form_valid()` will save the form again, which resets the password and invalidates the session. You shouldn't call `super().form_valid()` or you should call it instead of `form.save()` and ignore its return value. You should return the redirect explicitly.

Comment: thanks all, those clarifications were useful and solved the problem! by returning `return redirect(self.success_url)` instead of `return super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)` the user properly got logged in. i can accept it if you post an answer

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for the helpful comment, you could post it as answer for me to accept

Comment: @sc28 Glad the comment helped. The answer by Shafikur contains the solution so I would accept that.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks man! it was exactly what i needed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already logged in after registration by this line

```
login(self.request, user)
```

You may need to redirect homepage. SO, you need to chnage this line

```
return super(SignUp, self).form_valid(form)
```

to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name'))
```

Comment: You need `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name')` or `redirect('url_name')` if you want to use a pattern name.