# How to manually authenticate a user after registration when using custom login?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.5

Perhaps the most interesting feature of Django 1.5 is the `custom user` that finally bids farewell to the outdated username.

There is an excellent nearly [out-of-the-box example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) in the documentation to create a user where you would need only the email address instead of username.

There is however a small caveat.  For some reason after a successful signup, I am not able to login the user automatically as it would have worked as described in Django 1.4 in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222549/how-to-automatically-login-a-user-after-registration-in-django)

In other words, this doesn't work for me:

```
user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password2'])
login(request, user)
```

The strange part is I am not even getting any error message in the debug console nor any warnings.

According to the [out-of-the-box example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) though there is no custom backend defined. Only a CustomUser and CustomUsermanager.  Hence I don't understand why I can't login the user manually.

btw I also have set the following in the settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

Any Django 1.5 expert around here?

Comment: Did you tried change `authenticate` first arg to `email` instead of `username` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. After debugging in the internal django classes. The solution is embarrassingly simple.

```
user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password2'])
login(request, user)
```

My mistake was the wrong namespace for `login(request, user)`

Make sure you are using

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

And not by mistake:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

everything else was correct in my settings.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the example myself, and it did work.

Did you set the **AUTH_USER_MODEL** before running *syncdb* ?

If not, erase your DB and run the command again. Based on the linked example it should ask you  your date of birth while creating the superuser if everything is configured correctly.

And by the way, the *ModelBackend* is the default **AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS**, you don't have to set it.

Comment: +1 for your help and your tip. I finally found the solution though. Hope it helps others in same situation