# Log in automatically after registering

Tags: python, django

In django 1.9, how do you automatically log in the user after they have registered?

I followed the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222549/how-to-automatically-login-a-user-after-registration-in-django), but I get [this error](http://dpaste.com/0T6CJBT) when trying it out.

I added `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)` to settings.py

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm
from .forms import UserProfileForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login

# Create your views here.
def RegisterView(request):

    registration_success = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='uf')
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='upf')

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_atr = user_form.save()
            user_atr.set_password(user_atr.password)
            user_atr.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user_atr

            profile.avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')

            profile.save()
            registration_success = True
            user_atr = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],
                                    password=request.POST['password'])
            login(request, user_atr)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm(prefix='uf')
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(prefix='upf')

    return render(request, 'profile/register.html', {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form': user_form})
```

And my forms.py:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'field-input-element'

    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }


class  UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'field-input-element'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('display_name', 'avatar', 'birthday', 'usertype', 'daw', 'usergenre', 'gender')
        widgets = {
            'birthday': AdminDateWidget(),
        }
```

Comment: Try `request.POST.get('username')` and `request.POST.get('password')` instead.

Comment: @rinti - that would prevent the error, but won't help, because it will try to authenticate with `user=None` and `password=None`.

Comment: You don't need to set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your settings, because you are using the default value.

Comment: Please include the traceback in your question rather than linking to an image. It helps other users find your question in future.

Comment: @Alasdair If you did actually look at the "image" you'd see that not only is it not an image, but it also has the traceback!

Comment: I did look at the traceback already, sorry for mistaking it for an image. My point is that if you include the text this post, it will help users searching for key words, for example in this case, `MultiValueDictKeyError`.

Comment: Alright. I'll do that next time. :) Thanks for your answer by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a prefix for your form, so the data will be posted as `uf-username` and `uf-password`. Therefore `request.POST['username']` gives a `KeyError`.

It's not normally a good idea to fetch data directly from `request.POST` anyway. Fetch it from the form's cleaned data instead, and let Django take care of the prefix and validation.

```
user_atr = authenticate(username=user_form.cleaned_data['username'],
                        password=user_form.cleaned_data['password'],
                        )
```