# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_password' in django registration and login

Tags: python, django

I am entirely new to django.
Trying to create login and registration system.

User registers successfully, saved in database but I get this error after registering.

**"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_password'"**

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        fullname = form.cleaned_data.get('fullname')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        messages.success(request, f'Welcome to blaza {fullname}')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

When I remove "user.set_password" it works but registered users can not login with their credentials even when the username and password is correct, It says incorrect username and password. (only admin account, superuser can login).

So I researched and had to add the user.set_password and user = form.save (I get warning that local variable user value is not used)

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
fullname = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)
password2 = None

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'fullname', 'email', 'password1')

def clean_password1(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    try:
        password_validation.validate_password(password1, self.instance)
    except forms.ValidationError as error:
        self.add_error('password1', error)
        return password1
```

**Models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
class Meta:
    db_table = 'users'
fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile_pics', default='images/nophoto.png')
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                             message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 "
                                     "digits "
                                     "allowed.")
phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=13, default='')
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
has_store = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**signup.html**

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
<p>
  {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
  {{ field }}
  {% if field.help_text %}
    <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
  {% endif %}
  {% for error in field.errors %}
    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</p>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
path('accounts/', include('users.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Or Someone help me with a secured and working registration and login that actually works.

Comment: you currently have 2 user variables in your view `user = form.save(commit=False)` and `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)` that probally what causing it, if you want to check try to print out user in the view after authenticate() function

Answer (score 0):

In a simple signup form:

```
def register(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        fullname = form.cleaned_data.get('fullname')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        saved_user = form.save(commit=False)
        saved_user.set_password(password)
        saved_user.save()
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        messages.success(request, f'Welcome to blaza {fullname}')
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
 else:
     form = SignUpForm()
 return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

The reason you get noneType because you save user after the authenticate() so it return None

Comment: Worked but users cant still login with their credentials.I am getting this error  "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.". even if the credentials are correct!.

Comment: can you try to print out user to see what it show ?

Comment: Didn't show anything. Only superuser(admin) can login.

Comment: then the problem must be in your authenticate. How about remove request from authenticate() and remove the `if user is not None` check

Comment: and also post your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` of the django settings

Comment: Removed 'request', didn't work. Removed 'if user is not none' got this error ''AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta''. I added `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)` to settings.py but still not working

Comment: please i'll be sincerely needing your help on this. Thanks.

Comment: i tested the view function on my side and it work normal, i don't know what wrong with on your side, you can view the suggestion code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222558/11225821) answer