# Django redirect user after successful registration not working

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and building a registration system. When user registers successfully, it redirects to thesame registration page instead of home.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            saved_user = form.save()
            saved_user.set_password(password)
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("home")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                print(form.error_messages[msg])

            return render(request=request,
                      template_name="registration/register.html",
                      context={"form": form})

    form = UserCreationForm
    return render(request=request,
              template_name="registration/register.html",
              context={"form": form})
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div style="text-align:center"><h2>Register</h2></div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        <p>If you already have an account <a href="/login" target="blank"><strong>login</strong></a></p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use reverse to be able to use url name in redirect()

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(reverse("home"))
```

or if you don't want reverse

```
return redirect("/")
```

Comment: oh wait i already answered this question for you in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58987086/11225821) you put the `saved_user.save()` before the hash password function in your view so authenticate will return `None`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are getting `user` as `None` in `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`. Because you are not saving the user after setting password. So following code should work:

```
saved_user = form.save(commit=False)
saved_user.set_password(password)
saved_user.save()  # <-- Saving the Password in User
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this is working for me :

```
 kdef register(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        password = self.request.POST.get('password', None)
        authenticated = authenticate(
            username=user.username,
            password=password
        )
        if authenticated:
            login(request, authenticated)
            return redirect("/")
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'register.html', {
    'form': form
})
```