# Why are users not logged in when using a customized backend in Django?

Tags: python, django

With gracious help from another member on here, I am using a customized backend that checks for two requirements to log someone in.

**backends.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class ProfileCheckBackend(ModelBackend):

    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        is_active = super().user_can_authenticate(user)
        return is_active and getattr(user.profile, "approved", False)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django_site.backends.ProfileCheckBackend",
    # "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"

]
```

This works great, but when a user tries to sign up, they need to be logged in to move to the next function:

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_object = form.save()
            user_object.is_active = True
            user_object.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = make_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
            # user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            # messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in!')
            return redirect('sign_up_post')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required()
def sign_up_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
...
```

The login function, however, does not log the user in. How can I fix this?

Comment: register function does not require login as denoted by no @login_required() decorator. After the register function has been exited, a user and profile are saved to the database.

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your code... Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222549/how-to-automatically-login-a-user-after-registration-in-django answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried using authenticate and it returns NONE for the user.