# Creating a Register Page by using DJANGO

Tags: python, django, crud

How can I redirect in such a way that whenever a new USER  account is created in my site in "REGISTER" page then after the creation of that account, the account should get logged in simultaneously into my website??

Comment: Hi @Sudhansu Sekhar! Could you please elaborate on your problem? Can you update your question by adding some details, such as the code you already written to achieve this? You can be help by the following tutorial as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222549/how-to-automatically-login-a-user-after-registration-in-django

Answer (score -2):

Using Django form we can create registration page and edit a/c to your requirement using Django forms and template tags find below refrence.
https://pythonprogramming.net/user-registration-django-tutorial/
https://carlofontanos.com/creating-a-registration-page-in-django/