# Django password not hashed when creating new accounts

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and am trying to discover why creating new accounts via my account form do not hash the password (I assume the passwords are not hashed because I cannot log in using the password when the account is created, and this message shows under the password field in the django admin for accounts created via the form: `Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm`). I can successfully create new accounts in the django admin that do not have this un-hashed password issue.

views.py:

```
@unauthenticated_user
def create_account(request):
    form = AccountForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        # should hash the password, check username/email doesnt already exist, etc
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Count not create account.")

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/create_account.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.first_name

    pass
```

Create account form:

```
<form action="{% url 'create_account' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The form:

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account  # which model we're building a form for
        # password not hashed and requires username even if username omitted from fields
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username']
```

I'm following a tutorial series where the only difference with my code is that I extend from the `AbstractUser` model with the `Account` class (so that I can change the create user form to only require an email and password instead of a username and password). Unless I'm incorrect, I thought the `AbstractUser` model should automatically hash passwords for you.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You call `user.set_password(raw_password)` and it handles the hashing for you. Docs found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/. Note that you have to manually save it once you have set the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@purple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68515047/django-password-not-hashed-when-creating-new-accounts#comment121086447_68515047) mentioned, use [***`set_password(...)`--Doc***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) method as

```
@unauthenticated_user
def create_account(request):
    form = AccountForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)  # set `commit=False`
            user.set_password(
                form.cleaned_data["password"]
            )  # call `set_password(...)` with "raw password"
            user.save()  # save the actual User instance
            return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Count not create account.")

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/create_account.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use set_password method

```
def create_account(request):
    form = AccountForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        # should hash the password, check username/email doesnt already exist, etc
        if form.is_valid():
            form.set_password(request.POST['password'])
            form.save()
            return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Count not create account.")

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/create_account.html', context)
```