# Django can't identify the user after registering an account *AnonymousUser*

Tags: python, django, authentication

So the goal is for a new user to register an account and then get redirected to the home page and **recognized**. So that the user does not have to register for their account then go through the process of logging in right after. I want a standard registration, like Instagram, Twitter, and other professional applications.

So far, I'm where the user can register and redirect them to the homepage, but when I try to print their name on the screen, I get AnonymousUser. The user's information is written to the database after registering, but Django doesn't know who the user is. For Django to know who is logged in after registering, they have to log out and then log in right after registering their account. If anyone could help, I would be much appreciated it.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()


    return render(response, "register/register.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: How do you see email verification fitting into this?

Comment: Hey @KyeRussell, sorry I'm a little confused about your question? Are you asking me if I could use the same method above for verifying if a user's email exists?

Comment: Show what you have for your `RegisterForm`.

Comment: `class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]` @MoiMyazz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the authenticate() and login() functions:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Thanks for registering. You are now logged in.")
            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                    )
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
```

[originally answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222558/8401179)

after successful registration **POST REQUEST** explicitly log in the users using the **login method** and you can access the name of the user without having the user to login again...